# Firebase Object Not Found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Guys i was making a simple application using Firebase and i was uploading an image and also downloading it sometime later. Uploading works perfectly well but when i try to download an error occurs that says. Object profile_pics not found. I have created a folder named profile_pics and i store the image inside that folder. The image is there but gives error while downloading. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Here is what is in the console.

> Error -: Object profile_pics does not exist.

Here is the code to download the image.

```
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://dd-dd-dd.appspot.com/profile_pics/\(profileURL)")
    print("Path Full \(storage.fullPath)")
    storage.data(withMaxSize: 11 * 1024 * 1024, completion: {
        (data, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("Error -: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else{
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            cell.profileImageView.image = image
        }
    })
```

What could be the possible error? If you please guide me through this.

Comment: I pretty much copy and pasted your code and it worked for me. Double check the google space URL. Oh, and also make sure you added the App in the Firebase console and also exported the correct GoogleService-Info.plist file and added it to your project. Perhaps it's pointing at the wrong location.

Comment: @Jay If the info.plist file was not correct then i would not have been able to upload data to Firebase storage and real time database and authenticate. But all that works pretty much fine. Only problem is this downloading image.

Comment: Are you sure profileURL is a) Not null, and b) Just the file name and not some separate URL of its own?

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally created the profile_pics folder in a different project? The string following the forURL in the code snippet should match the string that's blacked out in the screen shot.

Comment: I copied the url from Firebase and pasted it to the project                                                                 gs://todo-app-7bb96.appspot.com/profile_pics                                                       The complete link is above. and i pasted it but nothing happens.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned - I copy and pasted your code into a new project, created a folder in my Firebase storage and uploaded a png to it. Using the exact code in your question, other than the URL, it worked for me. Do you have *FIRApp.configure()* in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function?

Comment: @Jay I have done that too. But didn't still solve the problem. I think i have to do it from the start and making new app in Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

I recover it this way.

```
   let url = URL(string: "\(ImageUrlSavedinDatabase)")

  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
         guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

                   DispatchQueue.main.sync() {
                   self.profilepicimageview.image = UIImage(data: data)
                   self.actIndicator.stopAnimating()
             }
       }
   task.resume()
```

Does that work?

Niall